# what hook should I use to output extension after body text

Tags: php, mediawiki

Using mediawiki. 
I have installed the extension [http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Contribution_Credits](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aContribution_Credits), which is called with the main body text `<?php $this->html('bodytext') ?>` in my `skin.php` file. 
I would like to insert some code (comment section) inbetween the main body text of my page and the contribution credits. 
At the moment the contribution credits extension uses the hook: 
 `$wgHooks['OutputPageBeforeHTML'][] = 'addFooter';` what can I change this to so it isn't called with the main body text but rather just above the `{ $this->html('catlinks'); }` section?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any hooks at that exact spot. You can use the [SkinAfterContent hook](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/SkinAfterContent) to put content immediately after the category links. That's probably the best you can do without creating your own skin.

**Edit:** To use the hook in the contribution credits extension, try this:

Comment out the OutputPageBeforeHTML hook and add the SkinAfterContent hook like this:

```
#$wgHooks['OutputPageBeforeHTML'][] = 'addFooter';
$wgHooks['SkinAfterContent'][] = 'addSkinAfterContentFooter';
```

Then create a new function in the extension file that looks like this:

```
function addSkinAfterContentFooter(&$data, $skin) {
    $title = null;
    addFooter( $title, $data );
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I get an error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class SkinMonoBook could not be converted to string in .. when using that hook.

Comment: I have created my own skin but I can't figure out how to change the extension so I can call it separately in my skin.